Get one unique value in several lists in Python
I have this data:
data = {23: ['WA', 'NV', 'AZ', 'OH'], 24: ['NV', 'OH'], 25: ['NV', 'OH']}

I'm trying to get one unique values from each keys list, like this:
{23: ['WA'], 24: ['NV'], 25: ['OH']}

But in my current code, it returns something different, which is not what I'm expecting.
here is my code:
def get_unique_states(data):
    unique_states = {}
    all_states = set()

    for key, states in data.items():
        unique_states[key] = []
        current_states = set(states)

        unique_to_current = current_states - all_states
        if unique_to_current:
            unique_states[key].extend(list(unique_to_current))
        else:
            for state in states:
                if state not in unique_states.values():
                    unique_states[key].append(state)
                    break

        all_states.update(current_states)

    return unique_states

data = {23: ['WA', 'NV', 'AZ', 'OH'], 24: ['NV', 'OH'], 25: ['NV', 'OH']}

unique_states = get_unique_states(data)
print(unique_states)

I'm trying to keep each key value with one different list value; if there are no more unique values, keep giving the first key value to it.
But the output that I'm getting right now is:
{23: ['NV', 'AZ', 'WA', 'OH'], 24: ['NV'], 25: ['NV']}

But I need this data:
{23: ['WA'], 24: ['NV'], 25: ['OH']}


Could you be more specific about the kind of values you need to return? Please explain the output ("unique_states[23] should be ['WA'] because..." and so on) and preferably provide more than one example, or provide a more precise definition what "one unique values [sic] from each keys list" means to you.

On the first iteration of the loop. all_states is empty. So everything in the first list will be considered unique to that item, which is obviously wrong.

The second iteration will only exclude the states from the first iteration, the third iteration will exclude states from the first two, and so on.

@Jasmijn thank you for your comment, yes,yes the output of each key should be unique as possible, otherwise add a duplicated value

There are no states that are unique to 24 or 25. NV and OH are both in 23.

What happens if you also have 26: ['NV', 'OH']? 24 and 25 have already taken both states.

@Barmar yes, in that case i want to add a duplicate value to their list like 24:['NV'], 25:['OH']

This looks like a constraint propagation problem, these usually are best solved with dynamic programming.

how is that (dynamic programming)

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

for first element 23 you have empty all_states  so all states are unique and you get ['NV', 'AZ', 'WA', 'OH'] - you should check size of unique_states[key]  and if you have more than 1 value then you could get random.choice() (and other states remove from all_states, and if you have empty list then you have to get first value from original states.
